# How to remove margin from first li element in a ul set to inline-block when other li's have it set

Tags: html, css

In the code below all the `li`'s will have a left margin applied including the first one. This will push the first element to the right. I don't want the first element to be pushed, I want it to stay put while the other elements have margin added. How do I do this?

```
ul li
{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:10px;
    display:inline-block
}
```

Comment: `padding-left: 10px` instead of `margin`?

Comment: [first-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/)

Comment: The answer kind of depends on how your HTML is structured can you please post that ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1ym40n88/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo-class

```css
/* added to remove default styles given by browser */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul li:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello world</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

or you can also use `+` [Adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) css selector which will check if `li` has an next sibling and give `margin` to it

```css
/* added to remove default styles given by browser */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
ul li + li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello world</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
  <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't do anything. I set both blocks to position:relative btw

Comment: position:relative doesn't matters but i think you forgot to remove default styles given by browsers @Dan updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you will want to target all but the first element. This can be done using the following selector:

```
li:nth-child(n+2)
```

Comment: Here's the results of that  http://jsfiddle.net/1ym40n88/3/   They fold under the first element with this method